# DSE CQL Query for Solr Suggestor

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, autosuggest, search-suggestion

I am using DSE 5.0.1 version. Earlier we used facet query to show search suggestions. For performance reasons , looking for other alternatives to get suggestions and found solr search suggester component. But I couldn't find examples where suggester component is used from a CQL query. Its possible right?Can anyone help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and relatively easy - you just need to understand how to map XML that you want to put into generated `solrconfig.xml` into JSON that is used for configuration.

For example, we want to configure suggestor to suggest on the data from field `title`, and use additional weights from the `rating` field. As per [Solr documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/suggester.html) the XML piece should look following way:

```
  <searchComponent class="solr.SuggestComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">titleSuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">TextField</str>
      <str name="field">title</str>
      <str name="weightField">rating</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
      <str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str>
      <str name="contextField">country</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
  <requestHandler class="solr.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

In CQL, it will be converted

```
ALTER SEARCH INDEX CONFIG ON table ADD 
  searchComponent[@name='suggest',@class='solr.SuggestComponent'] 
  WITH  $$ {"suggester":[{"name":"titleSuggester"}, 
   {"lookupImpl":"AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory"}, 
   {"dictionaryImpl":"DocumentDictionaryFactory"},
   {"suggestAnalyzerFieldType":"TextField"}, 
   {"field":"title"}, {"weightField":"rating"}, 
   {"buildOnCommit":"false"}, {"exactMatchFirst":"true"},
   {"contextField":"country"}]} $$;

ALTER SEARCH INDEX CONFIG ON table ADD 
  requestHandler[@name='/suggest',@class='solr.SearchHandler'] 
  WITH  $$ {"defaults":[{"suggest":"true"}, 
    {"suggest.count":"10"}],"components":["suggest"]} $$;
```

After that you need not to forget to execute:

```
RELOAD SEARCH INDEX ON table;
```

And your suggestor will work.  In my example, the index for suggestor should be build explicitly because inventory doesn't change very often.  This is done via HTTP call like this:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/keyspace.table/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.dictionary=titleSuggester&suggest.q=Wat&suggest.cfq=US&wt=json&suggest.build=true&suggest.reload=true'
```

But you can control this by setting `buildOnCommit` to true. Or you can configure it to build suggestor index on start, etc. - see Solr's documentation.

Full example is [here](https://github.com/alexott/datastax-bootcamp-project/blob/master/cql/inventory.cql#L41) - this is an example of the e-commerce application.